# How to generate youtube video download link using javascript. Links of all possible video quality

Tags: javascript, html

What I want to do, is to write a javascript code which will take youtube video url (eg: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2WUijLhJaoY ) and can generate a download link in mp4 format and in all possible video quality (eg : 360p, 720p).

Please help me.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=2WUijLhJaoY&asv=3   
 this link is downloading a file having video information, but i can't find download links in it.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the npm modules I have used for my personal projects. https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-dl  Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you have it in Javascript + HTML?